# String manipulation with Javascript (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to remove the first 13 characters of a string with this code:

```
requestToken = requestToken.substring(13);
```

However, I'm getting "`has no method substring`" error with NodeJS, the code above that mostly recommended in the Javascript forums does not work with NodeJS?

Comment: Not the answer, but substring(0,13) won't remove the first 13 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it seems like requestToken may not be a string.

Try

```
requestToken = '' + requestToken;
```

and then requestToken.substring(13);

Comment: This is invalid syntax I believe.

Comment: Was referring to the `requestToken = " + requestToken;` bit. Think you're missing a `"`?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for the confusion, it shows up as a double quote for me. =]

Answer (score 5):

`substring` (and `substr`) are definitely functions on the string prototype in node; it sounds like you're not dealing with a string

```
$ node
> "asdf".substring(0,2)
'as'
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert `requestToken` to a string first:

```
requestToken = (requestToken+"").slice(13);
```

Answer (score 1):

`requestToken` must not be a string then.  It's likely some sort of object, and the string you want is likely returned by a method on, or a property of, that object.  Try `console.log(requestToken)` and see what that really is.

You also want `.slice()` for removing the front of a string.

And you will likely end up with something like:

```
myString = requestToken.someProperty.slice(13);
```

Answer (score 0):

Coercing it to a string may not solve your problem. console.log(typeof(requestToken)) might give you a clue to what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your object/variable:

```
console.log( JSON.stringify(yourObject) );
```

or it's type by

```
console.log( typeof yourVariable );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
requestToken.toString().slice(13);
```

or

```
if(typeof requestToken!="string")
{
   requestToken.toString().slice(13);
}else
{
   requestToken.slice(13);
}
```